# Create a radar chart for every index position in df

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

my dataframe looks similia to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F", "G"],
                    "Tldiffto3": [2.0, -3.0, 2.0,17.0,7.0, 
                      12.0,2.0],
                    "LZdiffto3": [0.94, -5.0, 7.0,29.0,4.0, 
                      10.0,2.5],
                    "SZdiffto3": [0.94, -5.0, 7.0,29.0,4.0, 
                      10.0,2.5],
                    "KZdiffto3": [0.8, -9.0, 10.0,8.0,3.0, 
                      11.0,4.5]})
```

The following code creates a  single radar chart:

```
# number of variables
categories=list(df)[0:]

N = len(categories)
# create angle by dividing the plot / number of variable
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

values = 
df.loc[df.index[0]].values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), 
          subplot_kw=dict(polar=True), dpi = 100)

   # Draw the outline of the data.
  ax.plot(angles, values, color='#1aaf6c', linewidth=1, 
        )
  # add the fill in  
  ax.fill(angles, values, color='#1aaf6c', alpha=0.25) 

# Fix axis to go in the right order and start at 12 o'clock.
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# axis per variable + add labels
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories)

# Go through labels + adjust alignment based position
for label, angle in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(), angles):
  if angle in (0, np.pi):
    label.set_horizontalalignment('center')
  elif 0 < angle < np.pi:
    label.set_horizontalalignment('left')
  else:
    label.set_horizontalalignment('right')

# Set position of y-labels to center
# of the first two axes.
ax.set_rlabel_position(180 / N)

# Add  styling.
# color tick labels.
ax.tick_params(colors='#222222')
#  y-axis  labels smaller.
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
#color of the circular gridlines.
ax.grid(color='#AAAAAA')
# color of the spine
ax.spines['polar'].set_color('#222222')
# background color inside the circle 
ax.set_facecolor('#FAFAFA')
```

Now I want to loop through the index and create a new subplot with a radar chart for each index i.E the name:

```
for i in range(df.index):
  ax.plot(angles, values, color='#1aaf6c', linewidth=1) 
  ax.fill(angles, values, color='#1aaf6c', alpha=0.25)
```

this did not work, not sure where the problem ist, would appreciate an explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is it overwrites the plots each time unless you create new subplots. I've also used `fig.tight_layout()` to avoid overlapping. You can adjust `nrows` or `ncolumns` for a better view:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df), ncols=1, figsize=(20, 12), 
              subplot_kw=dict(polar=True), dpi = 100)
fig.tight_layout()

for i in range(len(df)):
    values =  df.loc[df.index[i]].values.flatten().tolist()
    values += values[:1]

     # Draw the outline of the data.
    ax[i].plot(angles, values, color='#1aaf6c', linewidth=1, 
          )
    # add the fill in  
    ax[i].fill(angles, values, color='#1aaf6c', alpha=0.25) 

    # Fix axis to go in the right order and start at 12 o'clock.
    ax[i].set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2)
    ax[i].set_theta_direction(-1)
```

Output:

[image: radial_plots]

Comment: This works sort of well, except that the styling does not work longer and the legend for each plot is not filled with the name. I've added the styling code. When editing the nrows and ncols my data is not being plotted. Any idea why that is ?

Comment: `fig.tight_layout()` needs to be called at the end, after the `for` loop.  You could use `ax[i].set_title(df['Name'][i])` to label each subplot.  When `ncols` would e.g. be `4`, you can address the axes via `ax[i//4,i%4]`.

Comment: Thanks Johan, when I change it like you recommended the column number gets adjusted. len(df) is 7 here but more then 7 radar charts get displayed when changing ncol to anything >1 thought

Comment: What I still don't unterstand is why the code for the labels doesn't work, It only changes the ° to the clólumn titles in the last radar chart..

Comment: ax[i].set_xticks(angles[:-1], categories) fixes that fyi